# git freezing at push while compressing objects

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

hi I'm using Github to push some files from my local server to my Github repository. I accidentally included a 500Mb video file in the commit and I think this totally screwed up the `add/commit/push`.

Specifically, my command stalls at the `push` like this:

```
git push -u myGithubRepository master
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects:  97% (36/37)
```

It's been many hours and is still stuck.

I'd like to commit all the other changes I made so I don't want to revert back to what's on my Github repository. I just want to resolve this conflict. I'm a Git novice so please take it easy on me.

thanks,
tim

Comment: It's not actually frozen, it's just going to take a *very* long time to compress that giant object.  The other threads finished all the other objects' compressions, and that one big object, the video file, could take days to compress (depending on your CPU etc).

Comment: @torek, thanks I realized you are correct a few hours later when the process completed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@torek was correct, "It's not actually frozen, it's just going to take a very long time to compress that giant object."

Answer (score 7):

Is there some reason you *must* include the file in your repo? I would recommend you can take out the 500mb file of your repo, and store it somewhere else.

1. Stop the process (`^C`)
2. Remove the file, either by placing it in your `.gitignore` file or moving it out of the project completely.

   - If you do decide to place it in  your `.gitignore` file, you will have to delete the cache of the file from your repository: `git rm --cached <file>`. Otherwise, it will still appear in the project. **Note:** This will not *remove* the file at all, but just the repository's reference to it. The file will still be sitting in the directory after all is said and done.
3. Commit
4. Push
5. Happiness

Good luck :)